# This slide menu working on desktop, but on mobile not

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/8x2b040p/3/embedded/result/

This code works perfectly on desktop, and when is browser size adjusted to mobile screen size working, but on mobile cant open menu on touch.

Thanks in advance. I am new here!

```
(function() {

        var bodyEl = $('body'),
            navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');

        navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
            bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

})();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the HTML and CSS to the question as well, as they are essential to the question. You can use the Stack Snippet feature to make a live demo (hit Ctrl-M in the question editor).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add jQuery to the external resources of your fiddle. Add it in and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/8x2b040p/4/embedded/result/.

An alternative would be a vanilla JavaScript version that doesn't rely on jQuery:

```
(function() {

    document.querySelector('.nav-toggle-btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        document.body.classList.toggle('active-nav');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

})();
```

Vanilla JS version: https://jsfiddle.net/8x2b040p/5/

Comment: Tnx Jonny, on mobile version is not working. When I touch square to open menu, nothing. Maybe because 'click' function? What is alternate for mobile touch???

Comment: It works on my mobile, @Rale. What are you using? Did you try the Vanilla JS fiddle?

Comment: Yes, in chrome is working, but android browser not :/ Thank you!

Comment: Hi what I should change in this scrip to work on android browser, it's working fine on chrome, firfox and safari...? @Jonny

Comment: Rale, use [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) to find out.